# How to correctly read specific csv column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hey everyone my question is kinda silly but i am new to python)
I am writing a python script for c# aplication and i got kinda strange issue when i work with csv document.

When i open it it and work with Date column it works fine

```
df=pd.read_csv("../Debug/StockHistoryData.csv")
df = df[['Date']]
```

But when i try to work with another columns it throws error

```
df = df[['Close/Last']]
```

KeyError: "None of [Index(['Close/Last'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

It says there are no such Index but but when i print the whole table it works fine and shows all columns

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1ERF.png)
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8EzO.png)

Comment: I'm guessing you're first running `df = df[['Date']]`, immediately followed by `df = df[['Close/Last']]`. The first line modifies `df`, and results in all other columns being removed. Maybe you just want to do `print(df[['Date']])` and `print(df[['Close/Last']])`?

Comment: Not really i just wrote this code for example to show that it works only with one column                Even when  i do this                             df=pd.read_csv("../Debug/StockHistoryData.csv")     df = df[['Close/Last']]                 
it still throws error

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make sure you've read the guidelines for posting questions. As a rule of thumbs, post data and the attemps you've done to solve or answer your questions. Do not assume that the community will do the work for you. In this case, do share data so we may  see where the error might be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the first row of your CSV file.
It contains colum names (comma-separated).
From time to time it happens that this initial line contains a **space** after
each comma.
For a human being it is quite readable and even intuitive.
But *read_csv* adds these spaces to column names, what is sometimes difficult
to discover.

Another option is to run `print(df.columns)` after you read your file.
Then look for any extra spaces in column names.

Comment: Thank you for reply) Turns out you were complitely right when i printed all colomns with  print(df.columns) method i got                                                                                      Index(['Date', ' Close/Last', ' Volume', ' Open', ' High', ' Low'], dtype='object')          When i tried to delete those commas i got only one colomn with all those names.                    I have to use this data for complicated prediction algorithms is there are something i could to those names  to make them python readable?

Comment: Wrote  python script to format column names 
header = ['Date', 'Close/Last', 'Volume', 'Open', 'High', 'Low']
with open('StockHistoryData1.csv', 'r') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp, fieldnames=header)
    # use newline='' to avoid adding new CR at end of line
    with open('StockHistoryData122.csv', 'w', newline='') as fh: 
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fh, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        header_mapping = next(reader)
        writer.writerows(reader)  Thank you every one for help

Comment: You wrote *i tried to delete those commas*. You should delete **only spaces** (after each comma).

Comment: You can "filter out" these spaces passing *skipinitialspace=True* to *read_csv*,
but remember that skipping initial spaces occurs in this case also in data rows, not only in the header.